# Python script is not executing from PHP

Tags: php, python-2.7, shell, exec

I'm trying to execute this python file below, when a post request is sent to the apache webserver.  I've including screenshots that show the path and anything else that can be useful such as permissions (/usr/bin/python & executable).  Both php and py files are in the var/www/html/ folder.  Thank you in advance for any hep.  I've changed exec('load.py'), to exec('/usr/bin/python load.py') to no avail.

load.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import paramiko

f = open('blocked.txt', 'r')
f = str(f.read())
#print(f)
s = f.find('epip="')
e = f.find(' epname="')
string = str(f[s:e])
string = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', string)
string = string[0]
print(string)


hostname = 'xxx'
username = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('config firewall address \n ' + 'edit ' + string + '\n' + 'set subnet ' + string + '/32 \n ' + 'end \n' + 'config firewall addrgrp \n ' +'edit BlockedIPs \n ' + 'append member ' + string + '\n ' + 'end \n')
test = stdout.readlines()
print(string + ' has been added to the BlockedIPs group')
```

blocked.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$file = 'blocked.txt';
$arr = $_POST;
$fp = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Can not open!');
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $toFile = "$value";
fwrite($fp, $toFile) or die('could not write to file');
}
fclose($fp);

$command = escapeshellcmd('load.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;?>

<br>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Path]

[image: Permission]

Comment: Is there a error message? `exec` takes as 2nd argument an output variable and 3rd a return code variable, have you checked this?

Comment: Since the POST is coming from the device, I'm not sure how to view the error.  If a get, I would open the chrome console, but for a post request, not sure where to go to find any error info.  I do see the txt file is being created which lets me know the first part of the php file is working when it receives the post.  If I run the python code from cli without sudo, it works.

Comment: Hmm wonder, do I need to restart apache?

Comment: You can add debug information to the script and POST it. (You can send your own POST request using curl or using something like "Postman").